# Error when starting GWT application

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have created GWT-RPC login page which finds user in data base through Hibernate. When starting GWT-RPC application I receive this error. But program runs is fine. And tests are working fine.
What could be the cause?

```
[ERROR] Member 'stringTable' in JSNI reference '@com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader::stringTable' could not be found; expect subsequent failures
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: stringTable
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$DispatchClassInfoOracle.getDispId(CompilingClassLoader.java:173)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.getDispId(CompilingClassLoader.java:1043)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni$JsSourceGenWithJsniIdentFixup.visit(Jsni.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsNameRef.traverse(JsNameRef.java:121)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:182)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsArrayAccess.traverse(JsArrayAccess.java:75)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:360)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsConditional.traverse(JsConditional.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:815)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsReturn.traverse(JsReturn.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.printJsBlock(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:961)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitor.visit(JsSourceGenerationVisitor.java:59)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsBlock.traverse(JsBlock.java:52)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni.generateJavaScriptForHostedMode(Jsni.java:251)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni.getJavaScriptForHostedMode(Jsni.java:239)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.createNativeMethods(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.injectJsniMethods(CompilingClassLoader.java:1400)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1215)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:383)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader$RpcDecoder.visit(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsArrayLiteral.traverse(JsArrayLiteral.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsExprStmt.traverse(JsExprStmt.java:42)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAcceptList(JsVisitor.java:450)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.acceptList(JsVisitor.java:113)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.prepareToRead(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:320)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy.createStreamReader(RemoteServiceProxy.java:259)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:214)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:250)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:341)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:137)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:589)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:551)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Share your JSNI code, or any reference to stringTable in your code.

Comment: I didn't use any JSNI code...

Comment: Did you use stringTable anywhere? And bind it?

Comment: But this field "stringTable" is in decompiled file ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:

<code> public final class ClientSerializationStreamReader extends
    AbstractSerializationStreamReader {
  private static class RpcDecoder extends JsVisitor {
...
    State state = State.EXPECTING_PAYLOAD_BEGIN;

    List<String> stringTable = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<JsValueLiteral> values = new ArrayList<JsValueLiteral>();
    
...<code>